# Is there a way to automatically e-mail after a long script is finished?

Tags: bash, scripting, mutt

I am trying to run a long bash script overnight to get some data. I wanted to include a script that would automatically e-mail me the files after the scripts are completed. Is there a way to do this using mutt? I want something like below:

```
sh atoms.sh  
sh angles.sh
mutt -a atoms.dat angles.dat -- [e-mail adress]
```

Any takers?

EDITS: If there's any other way to achieve this -- "sending multiple attachment to an e-mail address after scripting is finished" -- I'd be very appreciated.

Comment: Something like what you propose would work. But it depends a lot on your particular situation - what applications do you have available, how large are the data sets and so on. How to email on the command line depends a lot on what email client you have available and set up for instance.

Comment: @Janne: The "mutt" that the OP refers to *is* an e-mail client. See http://www.mutt.org/.

Comment: @ruakh I know; I assumed he does not want to use mutt specifically or he would simply use it as above.

Comment: @Janne: But he explicitly asks, "Is there a way to do this using mutt?"; so presumably his problem is that he doesn't know how to tell mutt to send an e-mail using only command-line options, without terminal interaction. Which, come to think of it, is not a programming question. I think I'll suggest that this be moved to superuser.com . . .

Comment: You're right of course. Should learn to read questions more carefully.

Comment: thanks -- I didn't know superuser.com exists. It may worthwhile to check it out. As for the question, I don't have to use mutt if the basic tasks (described above in EDITS) can be achieved.

Comment: Thanks guys but I solved. what do I do with the original post?

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, and then accept it. That will benefit other people needing to do the same thing.

Comment: can't really post the answers within 8 hours since my rep is low. but here's the answer ...

Comment: sh atoms.sh
    sh angles.sh
    mutt -s "data set from atoms.sh" [email address] < ./atom.dat
    mutt -s "data set from angles.sh" [email address] < ./angles.dat

will disable the terminal interaction and send e-mails after the jobs are finished.

Comment: I added the answer as I nearly missed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
sh atoms.sh 
sh angles.sh 
mutt -s "data set from atoms.sh" [email address] < ./atom.dat 
mutt -s "data set from angles.sh" [email address] < ./angles.dat
```

will disable the terminal interaction and send e-mails after the jobs are finished

Comment: +1 for "will disable the terminal interaction". It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

> -a file [...]
>             Attach a file to your message using MIME.  To attach multiple files, separating
>             filenames  and recipient addresses with "--" is mandatory, e.g. mutt -a img.jpg
>             *.png -- addr1 addr2.

```
$ $( sh atoms.sh; sh angles.sh ) &&  mutt -s "man mutt" \
  -a grab.sh  raptor.mpd.ogg.m3u  scripts/bussorakel  \
 -- emailAddress@example.com < /dev/null
```

---

alternatively, you have:

```
$(sh atoms.sh; sh angles.sh ) & FOR=$!
wait $FOR 

mutt -s "last command done, sending email" (...)
```

[image: the received mail:]

Comment: The question is about how to send an email after jobs has completed and not about attaching files using mutt.